# Loop over NEW Record

Tags: postgresql

Writing an audit trigger. Inside the postgresql function I'm trying todo:

```
'INSERT INTO ' || able_name || ' (' || columns || ') VALUES ' || NEW || ';'
```

When NEW is turned into string, varchar variables will not have quotes around them. This will cause the insert to fail. Easier would be to turn all the column values of NEW into `varchar` values, and postgres would automatically cast them into right values - when `INSERT` is executed.

Can I loop over the NEW record without turning it into json? 
Looking around, I couldn't find good resource explaining how to work with Postgres Record type.

Comment: Most people simply store that as a JSONB value in audit triggers. See [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) or [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/) or [here](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/auditing-data-changes-postgres)

Comment: Yeah. Can't do that. Thanks for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your target table's structure is identical to the `new` structure, you don't really need to iterate over the columns.

Something like this will work:

```
create function audit_trigger()
  returns trigger
as
$$
declare
  l_columns text;
  l_table_name text;
begin  
  -- this builds the name of the target table dynamicall
  l_table_name := tg_table_name||'_audit';
  execute format('insert into %I select ($1).*', l_table_name) using new;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Even if you don't want to store the changed data as a JSONB column, you can still use JSON functions to iterate over the columns of the `new` record if think you need it nevertheless.

The following will store the list of column names of the new record in the variable `l_columns`:

```
select string_agg(quote_ident(col), ',') 
   into l_columns
from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(new)) as t(col, val);
```

Comment: I want to be able to interate over NEW's column values. So `record_to_array(NEW)` function would be create.

Comment: @MihkelL.: you didn't mention you need the values as well in your question (only the column names). But jsonb_each_text() will also gives you the values. But why do you need to iterate in the first place? Doesn't the INSERT in my trigger do what you want without iterating?

Comment: If you look at the insert I'm trying todo. I don't want to use json for it turning NEW into it's values.

Comment: You don't need to turn anything into anything as my first example shows. But if you really need to _iterate_ over column names and values, there is no other choice (but the code in your question shows no indication that any iteration over the values is needed).